# How to convert dictionary with multiple values into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I would like to convert a python `dict` to a pandas `dataframe`. The number of columns should be equal to number of values for a particular key. From the example below, column names should be `i`, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` where `i` is dictionary key and rest are values:

```
e = {}
for i in range(0,len(length_of_the_row)):
    e[i] = a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`.from_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
import pandas as pd
e = {}
for i in range(0, len("length_of_the_row")):
    e[i] = "a", "b", "c", "d"

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(e, orient='index')
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn the dictionary directly into a `dataframe` and then transpose it since the rows and columns need to be swapped:

```
import pandas as pd
e_df = pd.DataFrame(e) 
e_df = e_df.T
```